# Запись чисел в файл Java

Tags: java, кодировка

Провожу запись элементов массива в файл

```
try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\prg1\\Letter.txt", false);) { 
     for(int i=0;i<mas.length;++i){
         writer.write(mas[i]);
         writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
     }
} catch(IOException ex){
     System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Проблема в том, что в исходном файле "`Letter.txt`" вместо чисел непонятные знаки. Может как-то при записи чисел указывать кодировку ?

Comment: Ваш код вызывает метод (write)[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#write(int)], который записывает символы по их аски кодам. Поэтому и непонятные символы.

Comment: Вы записали в файл не число. А байт который кроме как байта может иметь и -1 поэтому там тип Int.

Answer (score 2):

Метод `java.io.FileWriter.write` записывает в файл не строковое представление числа, а символ с кодом, содержащимся в этом числе. Естественно, что в файле появляются непонятные знаки. Чтобы правильно записать строковое представление чисел в файл, необходимо вначале это строковое представление получить. Для этого можно использовать метод `Integer.toString`. Нижеследующий код иллюстрирует применение этой техники.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;

class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] array = new int[10];
        final Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
            array[i] = random.nextInt();

        try (final FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:/Temp/Letter.txt", false))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
            {
                final String s = Integer.toString(array[i]);
                writer.write(s);
                writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Вот так будет правильно записывать:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

  try {
    File fileDir = new File("c:\\temp\\test.txt");

    Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream(fileDir), "UTF8"));

    out.append("some UTF-8 text").append("\r\n");

    out.flush();
    out.close();

    } 
   catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
   {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   } 
   catch (IOException e) 
   {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class JavaApplication2 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(13);
        list.add(44);


        try(FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("file")){
            int max = list.size();
            if(max > 0){ // size > 0 
                out.flush();
                //Чистка файла, если надо оставляем

                int i = 0;
                int a;
                while(i<max){
                    if(i > 0){
                        out.write(10); // /n

                        //Выйдет цепочка
                        //13
                        //44
                        //ВНИМАНИЕ! В КОНЦЕ ЛИШНЕГО /N НЕТ
                    }

                    a = list.get(i);

                    out.write(Integer.toString(a).getBytes());


                    i = i + 1;
                }

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        //Чтение
        try(FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("file")){
            //Проще некуда, но на больших файлах это самый плохой вариант
            byte[] buff = new byte[in.available()];
            in.read(buff);

            System.out.write(buff);
            System.out.print(".END....");
            //В конце закрывающий .END....

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

Вывод:

```
13
44.END....
```